# jQuery Chosen is slow on IE, show results after x chars?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm using the chosen plugin (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) with 10K items in the select box
On IE9 & IE10 it's very slow.

Is there a way to speed up to plugin?
Was thinking that results only would show up after x chars searched for, but can't find any documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

That number of entries will likely be slow, no matter which plugin you use (assuming the plugin keeps the elements in memory the whole time).

If you REALLY need to have all of those options available, it may be faster to have a search performed server-side, and return the resulting elements, rebuilding the select box after wards. I'm not sure if 'Chosen' has this capability, but I'm sure there is a jQuery plugin around somewhere that would provide this functionality.

10k is a lot of elements to go through and prune - and it's fair enough to say, IE has always been a tad on the slow side for JS.

With regards to why it's not speeding up after providing a certain number of characters, I imagine it's searching the whole data set every time, instead of (if a character is added) a sub set (the previously returned results).

This could be improved, perhaps by using a result set history of some kind, but would required substantial development.

Edit: Something like this possibly? http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: In this case here i'm using grocery crud (http://www.grocerycrud.com/) and it uses Chosen for relations. So i kinda prefer to stick to Chosen

Comment: Fair enough - in that case perhaps look into https://github.com/meltingice/ajax-chosen ?